# Can't retrieve value from Input text (added with partial view)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table with input elements in some cells. I can't figure out why I can't retrieve the value entered by the user.

My HTML is served as is:

```
<table><tr class="addedItem"><td>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" value="0" />
</td></tr></table>
```

My jquery selector is:

```
$('table > tbody > tr.addedItem > td > input').each(
       function(idx,item){
               alert($(item).val());
         }
    );
```

can't figure out why those inputs always retrieve 0 (of course, after user inputs in them).

Thanks in advance. 
This jsfiddle is working as expected, I need to check something else on the rest of my code. 
http://jsfiddle.net/pp4Yd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by removing the partial view.
When I did the jsfiddle I noticed everything was all right, so the form delivered by a partial view was the only "unknown" scenario by me.

I suppose those elements were out of jquery scope, *i'll post a detailed answer later. Thanks all*

Answer (score 1):

no tr with class addItem. You can eliminate it or simply try below

```
$('table > tbody > tr.addedItem > td > input').each(
       function(){
               alert(this.value);
         }
    );
```

or if you have `form-control` for each input inside td then use below

```
 $('.form-control').each(function(){
                   alert(this.value);}
        );
```

Comment: Sorry, the class is there. I've deleted when pasted the code here. I'll create a jsfiddle

Comment: use this.value instead of this.val()... corrected in answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the problem was a form delivered by a partial view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `change()` event to get the updated value:

```
$('table > tbody > tr.addedItem > td > input').each(function (idx, item) {
    $(this).change(function () {
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the problem was a form delivered by a partial view.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `tr` element with the class `addedItem`.

Try doing it this way,

```
$('table > tbody > tr > td > input').each(function (idx, item) {
    $(this).change(function () {
        alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

Edit:

You'll also have to `bind` the `change` event to `each` element.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the problem was a form delivered by a partial view.